# is passing app = express() into another module the same as requiring the module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module

I am wondering what is the difference between passing app = express() into another module versus requiring express within that module instead.

if I was to pass app = express() like so:

```
var app = require('express');
app.locals.title = title;
require('somemodule')(app);
```

then in the somemodule;

```
exports = function(app) {
    console.log(app.locals.title);
}
```

would you be able to use the app.locals variable set in the core file if you was to require express again within another module like so instead.

```
var app = require(express);
console.log(app.locals.title);
```

if not would you have to redefine the app.locals within this module?

which method would be best to use.

Comment: Which version of express are you referencing?  Your first example would error out in Express 4x.

Comment: I usually use `module.exports = app` so that i can simply `require('./app')` in other modules that need access to app properties.

Comment: That's a good solution @KevinB.  I've answered thinking that this is some 3rd party module where that is not possible.  Also, I typically like to be more explicit about what is adding or removing things from my app, so I find passing it into a module to be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll assume you're using Express 4x.  In 4x, the module actually exports a function, so you'll need to first create the app, after requiring the module. Like so:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

If the module does something like adding middleware, or adding functionality to the `app` you create in *your* project, then it's only going to work if you first create the app, then pass it into the module.  See below:

```
var express = require('express);
var app = express();
require('middleware-adder')(app);
// app now has the middeware provided by my module.
```

Anything set on the app before passing it into the module you're requiring (like `app.locals.title` in your example), would indeed be accessible inside of the module.  As the author of a module, you'll need to be extra certain that the consumers are passing what you expect them to be though!

Hope this helps.